# Create a scratch org with specified unlocked packages installed?

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

Is it possible to create a scratch org with unlocked packages (available on the dev hub org) to be installed automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. The intended design is to use force:package:install to install packages post-creation:

```
sfdx force:org:create <params>
sfdx force:package:install -w <time-to-wait> -p package1
sfdx force:package:install -w <time-to-wait> -p package2
sfdx force:package:install -w <time-to-wait> -p package3
```

Answer (score 1):

The <strike>[force:org:shape](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm#cli_reference_force_org)</strike> [force:org:snapshot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm#cli_reference_force_org)
capability may eventually be useful for you but it is not GA yet:

> A snapshot is a point-in-time export of a scratch org. The export is
> stored in Salesforce and referenced by its unique name in a scratch
> definition file.

Comment: My understanding is that it will be the snapshot not shape feature for this.

Comment: You are right @PhilW. Corrected.